# Can't connect to my FTP server via ftp_connect()

Tags: php, ftp

I have some problems with `ftp_connect()`; I can't connect to my own FTP-server via ftp.localhost or ftp.edgren.myftp.org. I got this error message when I try to connect:

`Warning: ftp_connect() [function.ftp-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in ...`

I use this code: `$conn_id = ftp_connect('ftp.localhost') or die("Couldn't connect to localhost");`

What's the problem? I use the basic FTP-server program Wing FTP Server to host my server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think that the name 'ftp.localhost' is a valid host name?

Comment: localhost, edgren.myftp.org, 192.168.1.1, and my IP address does not work as host via `ftp_connect()`. What else can I test? :P Do I have to have an FTP-server on another server with an domain linked to it?

Comment: No idea. ftp.localhost looked wrong to me. If those other things don't work I can't help you.

Comment: @Erik Edgren Can you connect to the ftp server by other means, e.g. with the ftp command or with a browser ? Get that working first.

Comment: Everything is working - connection via the browser and FTP client. I got same error message in the command prompt though; unknown host.

Comment: @Erik Edgren Then it's a problem with dns/name resolution, not the code.

Comment: @nos Oh, okej. Then I have to look more further on the FTP-server :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to 127.0.0.1. Localhost is just an alias to that IP, so if localhost doesn't work, the IP will.

Comment: It prints the error message on `die()` - "Couldn't connect to localhost".

Comment: Interesting... Do you by any chance bind the ftp server to your IP, instead of to any host? Because if it's bound to a specific IP, you won't be able to access it at localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Additionally, I found this page when searching for the problem. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31080 . I don't know how relevant it is to your situation.

Comment: My FTP-server is not bound to a specific IP address :) I have visited the link you send and I couldn't find any solution for my problem there :/